# Space difference between list of figures and list of listings

Tags: floats, listings, lists

See attached gif

[image: Conflict]

You got any clues how to fix that? I’m using a Koma class.

Comment: There is probably some stretchable space after the heading. If you post an example code that reproduces this then someone will be able to show you how to remove it. However, removing stretchable spaces can make it difficult for `TeX` to find good page breaks.

Comment: You should post the example in the question, not in an answer. in any case, if the problem is the spacing in listings, you can load `etoolbox` and do `\AtBeginEnvironment{listings}{\KOMAoptions{parskip=never}}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 4):

The log file contains a warning:

```
Class scrreprt Warning: \float@listhead detected!
(scrreprt)              Implementation of \float@listhead became
(scrreprt)              deprecated in KOMA-Script v3.01 2008/11/14 and
(scrreprt)              has been replaced by several more flexible
(scrreprt)              features of package `tocbasic`.
(scrreprt)              Maybe implementation of \float@listhead will
(scrreprt)              be removed from KOMA-Script soon.
(scrreprt)              Loading of package `scrhack' may help to
(scrreprt)              avoid this warning, if you are using a
(scrreprt)              a package that still implements the
(scrreprt)              deprecated \float@listhead interface  on input line 8.
```

If I change the code to include the suggested package, I get the expected result.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrhack} %%% <---- ADDED
\usepackage{graphicx}           % benötigt für Grafiken
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{_img/Link.png}
    \caption[Link]{Eine Beispielabbildung}
\end{figure}


\clearpage

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Hello World}]
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    // Prints Hello World!
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That nailed it. Dafuq is scrhack. I’ll study the doc... Thanks man.

Comment: Is there something to take care of when using scrhack package?